# fixing user_input referenced before assignment

Tags: python, input, text, user-input

I am making a small python text based game, and Im having an issue with the global variable assignment.  Heres the code in question.

```
print("story text removed for length")
light = False
killer_location =2
wolves = True;
commands = ["n", "S", "E", "W", "north", "south", "east", "west", "look","use","pick up", "attack","jump","throw"]
inventory = ["testinventoryobjectforarray"]
user_input = ">"
def forestscene():
    print("You are in a small clearing in the woods. Tall trees in every direction.")
    print("You see a dirt road to the north of you. ")
    
    while user_input not in commands:
        print("...")
        user_input = input("> ")
        if user_input.lower() == "n" or user_input.lower() == "north":
            roadscene()
        elif user_input.lower() == "s" or user_input.lower() == "south":
            wolfscene()
        elif user_input.lower() == "e" or user_input.lower() == "east":
            print("The trees are too dense and it's too dark to proceed further east.") 
     

forestscene()
```

However upon running, each function call returns "local variable User_Input referenced before assignment". I've tried adding global user_input, however that only resolved the first line, and adding them to all the calls causes the code to end after the first user input.  Please help.

Comment: Put `user_input = ">"` inside the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/370357/4046632

Answer (score 0):

This is one of python trap - unintuitive scope resolution. Look at this examples

```
b = False

def f():
    if b:
        print("True")
        # b = True

f()
```

It works as expected and nothing is printed. But if we uncomment `b = True` we get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment`.

What happened? When python cannot find variable in `local` scope it search it in `global` one. That's why in first example it just checks value of global `b`. When python enters the function it parses the funcion searching for `local` variables inside (even if its unaccessible branch). That is why in second program it puts `b` into locals, but have no value yet. When we try to access `b` we get above exception.

To fix your program, put `user_input` into `def` function. Then it will become `local`

Answer (score 0):

Either put your `user_input` definition inside your function as a local variable or write `global user_input` at the start of your function to tell python to always use the global variable.